# jOOQ not generating DAOs with <daos> flag set to true

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, sqlite, jooq

I have refreshed my project, cleanly rebuilt it, Googled/searched StackOverflow for similar problems, read the jOOQ documentation, examined the build output for potential [issues](http://pastebin.com/3jwSSb3Q), etc.

I added a `<daos>` flag to my pom.xml to generate jOOQ Database Access Objects, since the jOOQ 3.2.0 online [manual says](http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/code-generation/codegen-daos/#N1288B) "DAO generation can be activated using the daos flag". According to the jOOQ Advanced Codegen [documentation](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/#N131AE) setting this flag to true generates not only DAO's, but also relations, records, and POJOs:

```
<generator>
    ...
    <generate>
        <daos>true</daos>
    </generate>   
</generator>
```

Prior to adding the flag to my pom, I had auto-generated records and relations but neither POJOs nor DAOs. After adding the `daos` flag and rebuilding my project, I also have POJOs plus the other two but I still don't have any DAOs. The attached screenshot shows my generated classes. The classes added by the  flag are in the [blue box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9eIwL.jpg). I think there should be a package named something like "daos" with PurchaseDAO and UserDAO classes.

The jOOQ DAO [documentation](http://www.jooq.org/doc/2.6/manual/sql-execution/daos/) doesn't explain any cases where the flag is added but DAOs aren't generated. Part of the point of this project is to learn jOOQ so manually coding DAOs with jOOQ classes won't solve my problem.

EDIT: My SQLite 3.7.11 schema from the working and non-working solutions are [here](http://www.pastebin.com/NMrBn7uq).

Comment: Just checked JOOQ version 3.2, all is good, DAOs are generated, BTW, generated DAOs are simple implementation of the org.jooq.impl.DAOImpl, most DAO methods are present in that class, in generated just a few find/fetch additional methods.

Comment: No @SergiiZagriichuk, they aren't being generated in my project despite the daos flag. I wouldn't ask the question if DAOs were being generated.

Comment: maybe you also need the `<pojos>true</pojos>`?

Comment: @assylias no daos - > enables pojos

Comment: @JaneGoodall have you tried from console or just from Eclipse ?

Comment: Again, I've tried mvn clean org.jooq:jooq-codegen-maven:3.2.0:generate all is good, could you provide your errors ?

Comment: The build output is here: http://pastebin.com/3jwSSb3Q. It includes the config file and <daos> is true there too. I don't get any errors.

Comment: Building it from the console produced the same result.

Comment: have you keys in your tables ?

Comment: Yeah, each table has an autoincremented primary key column called row_id (all SQLite databases do by default, should have mentioned that in the post). However, neither jOOQ Table class has a row_id.

Comment: @JaneGoodall, I've just added as answer description about skipping DAO generation, Could you provide your SQL for creating tables ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've found in your console output that DAO is skipping,

> INFO: Generating DAOs           Jan 16, 2014 12:40:45 PM
>   org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info INFO: Skipping DAO generation  :
>   PurchaseDao.java Jan 16, 2014 12:40:45 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger
>   info INFO: Skipping DAO generation  : UserDao.java Jan 16, 2014
>   12:40:45 PM org.jooq.tools.JooqLogger info INFO: Table DAOs generated 
>   : Total: 212.968ms, +1.759ms

After that cheked code  and found next

```
// [#2573] Skip DAOs for tables that don't have 1-column-PKs (for now)
1287        if (keyColumn == null) {
1288            log.info("Skipping DAO generation", getStrategy().getFileName(table, Mode.DAO));
1289            return;
1290        }
```

Comment: Wow thanks, that looks like the solution. I'll regenerate the table to use non-row_id primary keys. If it works I'll  upvote this and mark it as Accepted.

Comment: If anyone else is reading this, you may have to refresh your project to see the DAOs. Just right-click the project in Eclipse and select Refresh.

Comment: @JaneGoodall: Very interesting! Would you mind adding a DDL of the table with "row_id primary keys" to your question for future visitors to understand what might be going wrong? I guess this is quite SQLite-specific

Comment: The db user that i was using didn't have permission to return primary key information. So i tried with an user that has elevated permission and the DAO got created. The DB is Postgres and probably the user is missing permission on information_schema or some other table where these information needed to generate resides.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem today (2017).

In your configuration file, the same used on line command, 
e.g:

```
java -classpath jooq-3.10.2.jar:jooq-meta-3.10.2.jar:jooq-codegen-3.10.2.jar:mysql-connector-java-5.1.45-bin.jar:. org.jooq.util.GenerationTool
```

In **configuration.xml**, put between the tags "generator" the tag "generate" with parameters respectively.

E.g:

```
<generator>
    ...
    <generate> 
        <pojos>false</pojos>
        <daos>true</daos>
         ...
    </generate>   
</generator>
```

See more about these the parameters [here](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.4/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/#N267BE).

Answer (score 0):

The configuration `includePrimaryKeys` must be settled.

```
<includePrimaryKeys>true</includePrimaryKeys>
```